# How to lock an Access database against writes

Tags: perl, ms-access, odbc, ms-access-2013

I can't find the answer to this question and it's hard to be sure by experimenting.

I am bulk loading multiple tables into a Microsoft Access database using Perl with [`DBI`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI) and [`DBD::ODBC`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBD::ODBC). All queries are done within a single transaction that gets committed at the end of the load (or rolled back on an error). The database is in a multi-user environment.

Ideally, I'd like to lock the database so that no other process can make any changes during my loading process, which only lasts about a minute and will be run once per day. One reason why this is important is that sometimes during the load I have to look at `@@identity` to get the autonumber ID of a record I've just inserted.

- What should my settings be for record locking? I am currently using

  ```
  Default Open Mode – Shared
  Default record locking – Edited Record
  ```
- Will the transaction lock the whole database against writes until it is committed? If not, is there a way for me to lock against all writes using `DBI::ODBC`?

Through experimentation I can tell that Access is doing some locking for me, but I can't be sure that it's a total lockdown.

UPDATE: The code looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use DBI; #database connection library

#open database connection
my $path='C:\Users\me\Desktop\mydb.accdb'; 
my $datasource = "Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=$path";


my $dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:ODBC:$datasource", '', '',
    {
            PrintError => 0,
            PrintWarn  => 1,
            RaiseError => 1,
            AutoCommit => 0,  
        }) || die "Error connecting: $!";



#Then I do various database operations.  Example:

#insert into database:
my $sth_insert = $dbh->prepare(qq{
INSERT INTO table1 (field1, field2)
values (?,?)
}) 

$sth_insert->execute($value1,$value2);  

#get back the autonumber ID: last_insert_id(undef,undef,undef,undef) is not supported
my $sqlQuery = 'SELECT @@IDENTITY';
my $sth_select = $dbh->prepare( $sqlQuery );
$sth_select->execute;
my $newId = $sth_select->fetchrow_array; #will this be reliable in multi-user environment with my settings?

#Then I commit the transaction:
$dbh->commit or die $DBI::errstr;
```

The whole thing is in an eval statement, so if it kicks out an error, I rollback instead of committing.

I'd rather lock down everything (reads and writes) if I can.

Comment: Please show your code. Are you sure you want to block only write access? Reads from the database could return spurious data if they're unlocked. Are you  updating multiple tables?

Comment: @Borodin - True, I'd rather block all reads and writes if I can.  I edited the post with the code.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you have a problem. The Id of a record appended by your process will not be stolen by another process.

Comment: I edited the code to add an insert statement and check @@identity.  Is that also safe, given my settings?  Is there a way to explicitly lock the whole database against reads and writes using Perl?  I would prefer to do that if I can.  Thank you.

Comment: The only option I know of is to open the database _exclusively_ but that requires that no other process has the file open.

Comment: It's only a handful of users and the load only takes a minute, so that would probably work.  I will look into how to lock exclusively using perl dbi:odbc with the MS Access driver, but if you happen to know offhand, maybe you can point me in the right direction.

Comment: Sorry, no. I have zero knowledge about Perl.